# How to remove two elements of collection at the same time? Task about cyclopes lenses

Tags: c#, algorithm, collections

I cant solve this task.

1. There are N cyclopes and an array of N elements.
2. Every element is eyesight value of single cyclop.
3. Every cyclop needs a lens with a value K but he will be okay with
   lens of value K+1 or K-1.
4. Cyclopes always buy lenses in pairs.

For example `5` cyclopes with eyesight values `[1,-1,2,3,-3]` will need to buy `3` pairs of lenses.

I need to write a program that will count *minimal amount of lens* pairs need.

I tried it like this

```
int cyclops = 4;
int[] cyclopsSightValues = { 1, 7, 4, 1 };
if (cyclops < 2) { return 1;}
List<int> list = cyclopsSightValues .ToList();
int matchCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        if (list[i] == list[j] ||
            list[i] + 1 == list[j] ||
            list[i] + 2 == list[j] ||
            list[i] - 1 == list[j] ||
            list[i] - 2 == list[j])
        {
            
            int valueToRemove1 = list[i];
            int valueToRemove2 = list[j];
            list.Remove(valueToRemove1);
            list.Remove(valueToRemove2);
            matchCount++;
           
            continue;
        }
    }
}
return matchCount + (cyclops-matchCount*2);
```

I think i need to find matching eyesights and *remove them from list*, but the result always comes out less then the correct one by 1.
Maybe my *logic is wrong* altogether?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"I tried it like this"_ - and what went wrong (hint, 1) when you remove element from the list the rest of it is shifted resulting in all remaining values indexes decreasing 2) `Remove` will remove all the matching values, so `.Remove(1)` will remove all `1s` in the list)

Comment: Also let's imagine that 0th cyclops sight matches  with the 1st and 3th, 1st matches  with 0th and 2nd and 3th matches only with 0th. If you remove 0-1 as pair then 3th will have no pair (2nd too) but if you pair 0-3 then 1-2 can also be paired.

Comment: You can show respect for those who might try to help you by putting out the basic effort to ensure the indention of your code samples are right, and not way to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, if two cyclops have eyesight difference `2` or less by absolute value they can buy lenses which fit both of them, e.g.
`3` and `1` can buy pair of `2` lenses. Let's try to use *greedy* approach now: order cyclops by their eye sights and try
to use `spare` lenses as frequent as we could:

```
1, -1, 2, 3, -3 -> -3, -1, 1, 2, 3

-3 v -1, 1 v 2, 3 
   can use
  -2       1
```

So far so good all we have to do is to sort and scan:

```
private static int Solve(int[] cyclopsSightValues) {
  Array.Sort(cyclopsSightValues);

  int result = 0;
  bool hasSpare = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < cyclopsSightValues.Length; ++i)
    if (hasSpare && cyclopsSightValues[i - 1] + 2 >= cyclopsSightValues[i])
      hasSpare = false; // We use spare lense from the previous cyclope
    else {
      // we have to buy a pair, and now we have a spare lense 
      hasSpare = true;
      result += 1;
    }

  return result;
}
```

Demo:

```
int[][] tests = {
  new[] { 1, -1, 2, 3, -3 },
  new int[] { },
  new[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(item => $"[{string.Join(", ", item)}] => {Solve(item)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
[1, -1, 2, 3, -3] => 3
[] => 0
[1, 1, 1, 1] => 2
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZJFs5) yourself

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should more or less work:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> LensesToBuy(IEnumerable<int> cyclopsVisions)
{
    int? buf = null;
    var e = cyclopsVisions.OrderBy(v => v).GetEnumerator();
    while(e.MoveNext())
    {
        if (!buf.HasValue)
        {
            buf = e.Current;
        }
        else if (Math.Abs(buf.Value - e.Current) > 2) 
        { // cached value not compatible
            yield return buf.Value;
            buf = e.Current;
        }
        else
        {  // cached value is compatible
            if (buf.Value == e.Current) yield return buf.Value;
            if (buf.Value > e.Current) yield return buf.Value - 1;
            if (buf.Value < e.Current) yield return buf.Value + 1;
            buf = null;
        }                       
    } 
    if (buf.HasValue) yield return buf.Value;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
int[] cyclopsSightValues = { 1, 7, 4, 1 };

var result = LensesToBuy(cyclopsSightValues); //okay to pass array
Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
```